# Ef core6 message error "Nullable object must have a value"

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-6.0

**My DB data**
**Fee table:**

| HospitalId | DoctorId | Price | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | a5bf5fa0 | 100 | 1 |
| 08bbB233 | a5bf2G2f | 50 | 1 |

**TimeSlot table:**

| ID | Duration | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B233tb35 | 30 | 1 |
| 08bbB233 | 20 | 1 |

**Model and relationship**

Hospital and Fee one to many (hospital many to Fee; Fee one to Hopital).

Hospital and TimeSlot one to many (Hospital many to TimeSlot; TimeSlot one to Hospital)

**Class response:**

```
public class GetFee
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Fees> Fees { get; set; }
    }

public class Fees
{
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Discount { get; set; } = 0;
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

**Command CQRS**

```
public async Task<PaginatedResult<GetDoctorMCCResponse>> Handle(GetAllDoctorMCCByCurrentDoctor request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            Expression<Func<TimeSlot, GetFee>> expression = e => new GetFee
            {
               Id = e.Id,
// Point to Fee by relationship Timeslot -> Hopistal -> Fee
// Discount and Total fields is not present in the data retrieved from the database and I'm setting itself in the response
               Fees = e.Hospital.Fee.Where(x => x.HospitalId != null && x.Status == 1)
                      .Select(x => new Fees
                            {

                                Id = x.Id,
                                Price = x.Price,
                                Discount = (decimal)0,
                                Total = Math.Round(x.Price - x.Price * 0 / 100, 2)

                            }).ToArray()
                   };

            }
            
            // I got the error "Nullable object must have a value" when arrieved this
            var data = _context.Fee
                .Where(x => x.DoctorId == "a5bf5fa0") // just test fixing Id
                .Select(expression)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToPaginatedListAsync(request.PageNumber,request.PageSize);
            return data;
        }
    }
```

My expectation I want to know why it got the error

> Nullable object must have a value

When I put `x.Status == 1` into the condition `Where()` in expression I got above error , If I remove it out will works normally I don't understand, Why it is related `x.Status == 1`?
Can someone explain to me what the issue?

Comment: This is an issue that yet is to be resolved in EF Core. What you can do is to cast the int to nullable. See here for more; https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22517 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26748